# I would like to create a graphical representation of a table using php?

Tags: php, database

There is a table of data which is updated regularly, I want to create a graphical representation such as a bar graph to represent the data. But on the page I would like to have a drop down box where you select one level. I suppose it  creates a cascade of tables so you have multiple layers so the top layer will show the over all totals, the next layer will split it out, the third level would split it out further.

Comment: Have you tried something at least?

Comment: No not yet I have the idea (sorry for my rubbish explanation above) but wanted to get a few resources/ methods first

Answer (score 1):

You could try searching for some libraries like [PHPlot](http://www.phplot.com/) to get you started...

Another aproach could be creating your own functions and using PHP to write inline styling to your bar elements, such as:

```
<div class="bar" style="height:<?php echo getHeight(elementIndex); ?>"></div>
```

This needs to be far more complex, but just to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you will give that a go :D

Answer (score 0):

Use phpgraphlib it is super easy to use, free and there is no company logos or links.

http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib

Comment: Thanks will have a look :D